# Exception: Cannot convert to int. in Google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have been trying to figure this out for days. I am trying to convert weekly sales from one Google Sheet into a table in a Google Doc using Google App Script. I want to email this doc out to certain people once the table is added.

When I am using the below code I am getting this error on appending the table into the Google Doc.

> Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for DocumentApp.Body.appendTable.

I have tried adding the [] around the [newRowDate] when appending the table but I am getting the same error. I have also tried adding the values to an empty array which has also not worked. Can someone help with a solution to have this table written to the Google Doc?

```
 function findWeeklySalesWeek1() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1BL5eflzP-jabdcMj7aV42qLd9BTRNM1qfMpw8ZIWkJ8').getSheetByName('Weekly Sales Totals');
 
 var rowData = sheet.getRange('A2').getDisplayValues();
 
 var newRowData = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1BL5eflzP-jabdcMj7aV42qLd9BTRNM1qfMpw8ZIWkJ8').getSheetByName('December Sales').getRange('A1:G7').getValues();
  
 var doc = DocumentApp.openById('1TsXuudVjY6mFyH-3VbpTBEgoQ24aAlc16qUxcpwz35Y');
 var body = doc.getBody();
 body.clear().setFontSize(9).setFontFamily('Montserrat');
 body.insertParagraph(0, sheet.getName())
 .setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
  
 var table = body.appendTable(newrowData);
 //var table2 = body.insertTable(rowData);
 //table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
```

Comment: Please have your post focused on one problem. Edit out other questions and post them as a separate one.

Comment: `newrowData` seems to be uninitialized. Are you sure error is not caused by typo? i only see `newRowData`

Comment: Also, i want to see the variable's value, can you log your data in the post?

Comment: I have figure this out! I have replaced                
```                                                                         
var newRowData = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1BL5eflzP-jabdcMj7aV42qLd9BTRNM1qfMpw8ZIWkJ8').getSheetByName('December Sales').getRange('A1:G7').getValues(); ''' with getDisplayValues() instead of .getValues()

Comment: That's fine as well. I assume your data is numeric and you want the string literal of the value. Or you could cast them into string too. both works I guess.. Im on mobile so I wasn't able to test your script. Feel free to post your solution and accept it for people to see that this post is solvable

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution to this question.

My error was that I was calling `.getValues()` on the newRowData variable instead of `getDisplayValues()`

Solution:

```js
function findWeeklySalesWeek1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1BL5eflzP-jabdcMj7aV42qLd9BTRNM1qfMpw8ZIWkJ8').getSheetByName('Weekly Sales Totals');
  var rowData = sheet.getRange('A2').getDisplayValues();
  Logger.log(rowData);
  var newRowData = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1BL5eflzP-jabdcMj7aV42qLd9BTRNM1qfMpw8ZIWkJ8').getSheetByName('December Sales').getRange('A1:G7').getDisplayValues();
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('1TsXuudVjY6mFyH-3VbpTBEgoQ24aAlc16qUxcpwz35Y');
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.clear().setFontSize(9).setFontFamily('Montserrat');
  body.insertParagraph(0, sheet.getName())
  .setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
  var table = body.appendTable(newRowData);
```

I hope this will help others find a solution to their issues in the future.

Comment: Good catch. welcome to stack overflow. As I've mentioned, you can still use `getValues` but you have to cast the data to string. but using `getDisplayValues` would be easier.